# Using with and if simultaneous in django template

Tags: python, django

my view : I have used templated_context_processor for my convinience

```
def list_subtest(request):
return {'subtest':Subtest.objects.all(),'test':Test.objects.all()}
```

my models :Here I have test and subtest models. For example Blood falls in test category and hemoglobin falls in subtest category

```
class Test(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Subtest(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='subtest',blank=True, null=True)
unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
reference_value = models.IntegerField()
selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

my template : I want to show the test and the subtest that falls under the same test .

```
<ul class="nav-list">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Test</a>
              <form class="hero-menu">
                {% for test in test %}
                <div class="category-block">
                  <ul class="dropdown-list">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><h4 data-modal-target="menu-test-popup">
                          {{test.name|title}}
                        </h4></a>
                    </li>
                    {% for subtest in subtest %}
                      {% with subtest.test as name %}
                       {% if name %}
                       <li>
                        <div class="checkbox-group">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="aUniqueName" name=
                          value="example"/>
                          <label for="aUniqueName">
                           {{subtest.name}}
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                       {% endif %} 
                      {% endwith %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `id` of `test` and `test_id` of `Subtest` are equal or not. If equal, then show the subtest under that test.

```html
<ul class="nav-list">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Test</a>
              <form class="hero-menu">
                {% for test in test %}
                <div class="category-block">
                  <ul class="dropdown-list">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><h4 data-modal-target="menu-test-popup">
                          {{test.name|title}}
                        </h4></a>
                    </li>
                    {% for subtest in subtest %}
                       {% if subtest.test_id == test.id %}
                       <li>
                        <div class="checkbox-group">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="aUniqueName" name="{{ subtest.name }}" value="example"/>
                          <label for="aUniqueName">
                           {{subtest.name}}
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                       {% endif %} 
                    {% endfor %}
```

I don't think if you need `{% with %}` here.

Another way could be to use `prefetch_related` with your `Test` model. It will get all the subtest for a particular test.

```py
def list_subtest(request):
    return {'test':Test.objects.all().prefetch_related('subtest')}
```

Then in your template, you can get subtest by iterating over `test.subtest.all`.

```html
{% for subtest in test.subtest.all %}
    <li>
        <div class="checkbox-group">
            <input type="checkbox" id="aUniqueName" name="{{ subtest.name }}" value="example"/>
            <label for="aUniqueName">{{subtest.name}}</label>
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In the template, test.subtest.all , is that subtest from prefetch_related('subtest')

Comment: test.subtest.all  is the subtest for a particular test. `prefetch_related('subtest')` indicates that get the subtest objects for each test object.

Comment: Note that you don't actually _need_ the `prefecth_related` call for this to work - it's a welcome optimization (less db queries).

Comment: agreed  @brunodesthuilliers, here `prefetch_related` is used to reduce the number of db queries.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the model method to get all the sub_tests under a test

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_subtests(self):#model methods
        return Subtest.objects.filter(test=self)



Class Subtest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='subtest',blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    reference_value = models.IntegerField()
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In templated_context_processor just pass list of Test objects:

```
def list_subtest(request):
   return {'test':Test.objects.all()}
```

In Django template:

```
<a href="#">Test</a>
<form class="hero-menu">
    {% for test in test %}
        <div class="category-block">
            <ul class="dropdown-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <h4 data-modal-target="menu-test-popup">
                        {{test.name|title}}
                    </h4>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% for subtest in test.get_subtests %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkbox-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="aUniqueName" name="example"/>
                            <label for="aUniqueName">
                                {{subtest.name}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: You should read the doc, it would save you useless efforts - this is alreay provided by the reverse relation manager (`test.subtest.all()` in your example).